# Error: Unexpected EOF while parsing. Trying to write to file

Tags: python-3.x

I am making my first script that writes things to file and I am getting an error.

```
import math

client = str()
wordcount = int()
client = str(input("Who will this be written for? "))
wordcount = int(input("How many words long would you like the story to be? "))

baseprice = 5
finalprice = int()
subfin = wordcount/600
finalprice = subfin * baseprice
print("\nClient: ",client,"\nWordcount: ",wordcount,"\nPrice: $",format(finalprice,".2f"))

f = open('clients.txt', 'w')
f.write("\nClient: ",client,"\nWordcount: ",wordcount,"\nPrice: $",format(finalprice,".2f")
```

Comment: `file.write` does not take a comma-separated list of items, just a single string. Post your full error message with traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is missing the second closing parenthesis.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are caused by typographical errors. These types of questions hold no value for future readers and should be closed & deleted, and answering potentially makes them harder to delete. A comment would have been better.

Comment: So comments cannot be answers, but some answers should be comments.  If answering a question that should be deleted causes problems, then there is a problem with how SO works.